# cocoa FTP connection authentication concern

Tags: macos, cocoa, ftp, ftp-client

I want to download a file from FTP connection for that I am using NSURL connection.
The connection have username and password.

If I pass the username and password in the url

ftp://user:password@ftp.example.com/foo/bar.zip

than it works fine. but I want to implement the authentication method where I can pass the password in the callback. But I am not receving any callbacks.

Below is the callback that I have implemented but it never gets called

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

Note:- I tried using Apple sample called SimpleFTPSample but it didnt helped.

Comment: Get a bit more into detail. Which part is not working? Any error codes? Which method is calling the callback?

Can you please post at least the relevant parts of the declarations and method calls?

And please provide the URL to the apple FTP stuff, is it the source code next to the http server stuff?

Willing to help, but with more information :D

Cheers,

living

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive callbacks, please check both things:

```
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestToServer delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
                                                                                                 ^^^^^^ must be
```

And u must call it from main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) { // u url part here
```

Then, u callbacks will be done, u can using authenticate part user name and pass trick can impossible to parse then from code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    NSString *user = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%s%@", 'u', "se", @"r"];
    NSString *password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%s%c%@", 'B', "FEBB", 'C', @"3CD036ED072A"];

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:user
                                                             password:password
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

But as i know, user and pass will be sent anyway without any protection, so better solution is moving u content to https server. In that case u can be sure that u